# Setters / Getters within singleton in Java

Tags: java, singleton, getter-setter

I need to create working setters/getters for a application, that will use few different classes. This classes will use one class, that will store all data. I know, when I will use standard constructor of container class, I'll get tons on nulls, due to different instance of container class.

I've created container class within a singleton, that works, but I wanted to ask, anything could be done better. My code:

Container.java:

```
public class Container {

    public static final String String = "Welcome in Singleton Container\n";
    private String Test = null;
    private String appName = null;
    private String appOwner = null;

    private Container(String mes) {
        System.out.println("Message from Container: " + mes);
    }

    private static class SingletonHolder {
        private final static Container INSTANCE = new Container(String);
    }

    public static Container getInstance() {
        return SingletonHolder.INSTANCE;
    }

    public String getTest() {
        return Test;
    }

    public void setTest(String test) {
        Test = test;
    }

    public String getAppName() {
        return appName;
    }

    public void setAppName(String appName) {
        this.appName = appName;
    }

    public String getAppOwner() {
        return appOwner;
    }

    public void setAppOwner(String appOwner) {
        this.appOwner = appOwner;
    }   
}
```

Sample class, that will use this container:

```
public class SecondClass {

    Container ctn = Container.getInstance();
    .
    .
    some methods...
}
```

Right now, when I use in main class ie.:

```
ctn.setAppOwner(owner);
```

I get a proper value in any other classes, when I call this:

```
Container ctn = Container.getInstance();
ctn.getAppOwner();
```

Is that a good approach?

Comment: `String String`, my eyes!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for a [codereview.se] of working code.

Comment: I suggest using an `enum` for a singleton.

Comment: "anything could be done better?" Certainly. Singletons, nullable fields and mutable classes should all be avoided where possible.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I try to only use singletons which are stateless.

Comment: I wasn't aware of "code review" If it's violating some rules, please close this topick. If able pls point me some way to get the answer, and don't violating any rules

Comment: If you decide to post at Code Review, make sure you've read the [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ResourceBundle concept.

```
public class Container {

    public static final String message = "Welcome in Singleton Container\n";
    private static Container container;
    private String test = null;
    private String appName = null;
    private String appOwner = null;

    private Container(String mes) {
        System.out.println("Message from Container: " + mes);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        ResourceBundle myResources = ResourceBundle.getBundle("application.properties");
        this.test = myResources.getString("app.test");
        this.appName = myResources.getString("app.appName");
        this.appOwner = myResources.getString("app.appOwner");
    }

    public static Container getInstance() {
        if( container == null ) {
            synchronized( Container.class ) {
                if( container == null ) {
                    container = new Container(message);
                }
            }
        }
        return container;
    }

    public String getTest() {
        return test;
    }
    public String getAppName() {
        return appName;
    }

    public String getAppOwner() {
        return appOwner;
    }
}
```

And you create properties file with name application.properties with following content.

```
app.test=test
app.appName=abc
app.appOwner=xyz
```

and place the file folder name in classpath

Comment: I was thinking about ResourceBoundle, but I thought, I'll try without any additional file in class path first.